# How to disable upload button during file upload and append

Tags: javascript, jquery

By fluke I realise an issue which would cause a big problem with my application.

I have my application here where it will upload videos. [Application](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/InputTest2.php)

The problem I have is that if you upload a video and then click on the `Add Question` button to append another file input in a new row, the `Upload` button in the new row is not disabled, this means that you can upload multiple files which I do not want as it will stop the first file uploading to stop uploading and potentially system ould crash if users try to upload large multiple files. My question is that if I click on the `Add Question` button , if a file is uploading, then the upload button in the appended row(s) should be disabled until upload is finished?

To use app follow steps below:

1. Click on `Add Question` twice to append 2 new table rows. In each table row you will see a file input.
2. In file input in row 1 select a video (I select a decent size video so that file is uploading while you complete other steps) and click on `Upload` to upload video. You will now see that the `Upload` buttons are disabled while video is uploading
3. Now while video is uploading click on `Add Question` button again to append another row. Now you will see that the `Upload` button in the newly appended row is not disabled while the file is uploading. I want this button and other upload buttons which are appended to be disabled if a file is uploading.

Below is Relevant code where it appends the table rows from the `Add Question` button:

```
function GetFormVideoCount(){ 
  return $('.videouploadform').length + 1;
}


var qnum = 1;
var qremain = 5;

function insertQuestion(form) {   

    if (qnum > 5) {
    return;
}


    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl_onthefly > tbody');
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>");
    var $video = $("<td width='17%' class='video'></td>"); 

              $('.num_questions').each( function() {

    var $fileVideo = $("<form action='videoupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target_video' onsubmit='return videoClickHandler(this);' class='videouploadform' >" + 
    "<p class='videof1_upload_form'><label>" + 
    "Video File: <input name='fileVideo' type='file' class='fileVideo' /></label><br/><br/><label class='videolbl'>" +  
    "<input type='submit' name='submitVideoBtn' class='sbtnvideo' value='Upload' /></label>" + 
    "<p class='videof1_upload_process' align='center'>Loading...<br/><img src='Images/loader.gif' /></p>" +
    "<input type='hidden' class='numvideo' name='numvideo' value='" + GetFormVideoCount() + "' />" + </p>" +
    "<iframe class='upload_target_video' name='upload_target_video' src='/' style='width:0px;height:0px;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>"); 

    $video.append($fileVideo);


    $tr.append($video);  
    $tbody.append($tr); 


}
```

Below is relevant code where when it starts the file's uploading process and where it disables the upload buttons in rows which are already appended:

```
   function startVideoUpload(videouploadform){

             sourceVideoForm = videouploadform;

            $(".sbtnvideo").attr("disabled", "disabled");


    }); 

          return true;
    }
```

Below is relevant code for function when uploading has finished:

```
function stopVideoUpload(success, videoID, videofilename){


      $(".sbtnvideo").removeAttr("disabled");


      return true;   
}
```

Below is video upload click handler:

```
   function videoClickHandler(videouploadform){ 
      if(videoValidation(videouploadform)){ 
          window.lastUploadVideoIndex = $('.videouploadform').index(videouploadform);
          return startVideoUpload(videouploadform); 
      } 
      return false;
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
function startVideoUpload(videouploadform){


               $(".sbtnvideo").click(function(event){
               $(".sbtnvideo").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    event.preventDefault();
    });

       return true;   
    }

    function stopVideoUpload(success, videoID, videofilename){


                $(".sbtnvideo").click(function(event){
                $(".sbtnvideo").removeAttr("disabled");
    return true;
});


          return true;   
    }
```

Comment: rather than using the deprecated 'attr' method to set disabled, use prop(): http://api.jquery.com/prop/ ... so like .prop('disabled',false), and then .prop('disabled',true)

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey I will use prop in future applications. Thanks for info :) It is just that this is final thing to do and I need to hand in tomorrow and I already wrote uo and showed examples of my code in other pages which used .attr()

Comment: Please read http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2011/06/html-difference-between-attribute-and.html for properties vs attributes, jQuery 1.9 removes the ability to set properties with attr() and http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2013/01/8-methods-that-will-not-work-in-jquery.html

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss So you are saying that because I am using .attr() that it is unable to disable upload button when appended to new row when file is loading, but .prop() would be able to do it?

Comment: Depends on the jQuery version somewhat. Otherwise, yes for 1.9 would seem to be an appropriate answer.  FWIW, If I had something like this, I would look at using jQuery Deferred to manage the async event.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Oh right, I have 1.7 Jquery, sorry I didn't see that you stated 1.9 jquery.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss There must be some sort of a way to do an if statement where when I click on `Add Question` button, if startupload function is happeneing, then disable upload else if stopupload or even just else upload is not disabled

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the default behavior of the button then reenable it later.

```
$(".sbtnvideo").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});

$(".sbtnvideo").click(function(event){
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Can I make it look disabled as well? DO I put the first function you mentioned in the `insertQuestion(form)` and add the disabled attribute and then in the `StopVideoUpload()` put the second function inside there?

Comment: I would add the preventDefault version to startVideoUpload, and the return true version to stopVideoUpload.  You can also easily make it look disabled by adding the disabled attribute to the button.  Make sure you have style there so that it works.  I'd add it to the html without javascript and look at the page to make sure it looks right, after that, add the code. JQuery themeroller has disabled classes built in.  I am using .removeClass('ui-state-disabled'); and .addClass('ui-state-disabled');

Comment: Can you have a look at update, I included demo to match with update but no change.

Comment: they are both stop, take another look

Comment: Sorry that was a paste mistake on SO, I will edit it, it is one on start and other on stop

Comment: Let me know how it works. Can you bump my answer if it works?  I need the points.

Comment: I always upvote and give best answers to correct answers. But at moment it is not working. If you know working version and show a code snippet of working sample then I will give you the best answer and upvote no problems, but at moment it isn't working

Comment: If you want to create a simple sample that I can put into a text editor as is and open with a browser I could fix this easily.  The sample above is not complete and I can't tell what is going on with qandatbl_onthefly, num_questions, or insertQuestion.  I am also not sure what the issue is except that it doesn't work.  The html might not exist or there might be another typo.  I typically create a stripped down question sample so there is no confusion and it is easier on the person answering.

Comment: Give me your email and I will send you demo file itself. The current demo link in app shows why it isn't working. Its is doing same thing, upload button not disabled when clicking on add question during a file upload